# CSV export to folder with foreach function

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have an php script, which i want to use to automatically export data from a certain mysql table, to a CSV file in a directory. The script is working fine and the files are saved in the right directory, but u want, that every order, exports to a separate CSV file.

Like:

- 12-09-2016-05-21_csvexport_1.CSV < data from order 1
- 12-09-2016-05-21_csvexport_2.CSV < data from order 2
- And so on..

I want to run the script automatically with a cronjob. The orders to be exported as a separate csv file, can be selected with a date range. Like only create csv files from the last 2 days. It doesn't matter if the CSV files are going to overwrite.
The order table looks like this:

```
id_order    date        customer
1       01-01-2016  1223
2       01-02-2016  1224
3       01-03-2016  1225
4       01-04-2016  1226
5       01-05-2016  1227
```

And the php script looks like this:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'pass';
$db = 'database';
$table = 'columns';
$file = 'csvexport';
$dir = 'csv';

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Can not connect."); 

function escape_csv_value($value) { 
$value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
if ( preg_match( '/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $value ) ) {
return '"' . str_replace( '"', '""', $value ) . '"';
} else { 
return $value;
} 
} 

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."");
$i = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$csv_output .= $row['Field']."; ";
$i++;
}
}
 
$values = mysql_query("SELECT id_order, date, customer FROM orders");
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
$csv_output .= escape_csv_value($rowr[$j]).';'; 
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
}
 
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".csv"); 

$filename = date("d-m-Y-i-s_", time()) . $file.".csv";

print $csv_output;
 file_put_contents($dir ."/".$filename, $csv_output);
}
?>
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: one more time review your question. It's not clear to me. Do you want to change the filename based on date period you search? Do you want to chunk the result? ... ?

Comment: I want to create separate CSV files, based on the order id.
Like:
File: 12-09-2016-05-21_csvexport_1.CSV < data from order 1 
  Results in CSV: 1       01-01-2016  1223
12-09-2016-05-21_csvexport_2.CSV < data from order 2
  Results in CSV: 2       01-02-2016  1224